# Resetting console.log to it's default functionality

Tags: javascript, default, console.log

On a live website, I've previously changed console.log to be:

```
var console = {};
console.log = function () {};
```

With this code always executing, is it possible to reinstate the console functionality after this code, and if so, how?

It's needed, since the site is live. But I need to do further development, without making any updates to the live site. It's hard without console logging/information.

Comment: No, you can't because by overwriting `console` you lose its original value. You need to cache that value somewhere in advance.

Comment: Why would you overwrite the default behavior of `console` in the first place?

Comment: @Ivar, since it's a large project, and having used console.log for debugging, I chose to overwrite console in production.

Comment: so no solution at all? is this how you shutdown console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that code is not running on the top level, because `console` is on `window`, you can just reference `window.console.log`, eg:

```js
(() => {
  var console = {};
  console.log = window.console.log;
  console.log('foo');
  // or, just reference window:
  window.console.log('bar');
})();
```

If the code is running on the top level and you're using `const` or `let` (rather than ES5 `var`), you can do the same thing:

```js
const console = {};
console.log = window.console.log;
console.log('foo');
```

Otherwise, you'll have to save a reference to `console.log` before you reassign `console` with `var`:

```js
var log = console.log;
var console = {};
console.log = log;
log('foo');
```

But it's probably not a great idea to create/overwrite built-in global variables like that unless absolutely necessary - the IIFE in the first snippet is probably preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 1 year and 8 months old by the time I write this, but I happened to figure out a good workaround solution.

You can set a global variable that will get the window.console object when the website loads and another global variable called "console" to get the old console state whenever you want.

```
var oldConsole = window.console;
var console = {};
```

So when you need to reset the console to its normal functionality, you simply do:

```
console = oldConsole.log; // since it's 'window.console.log'
console.log('Hello, world!'); // this output will now display on devtools with its default configuration
```